# Send an email when openshift pod is down

Tags: node.js, openshift, kubernetes-pod

If there are 2 pods (2 replicas) are running for the application. If one fails then it should send email notification.

Can i use any Openshift Rest API to continuously check the pod status by using nodejs application?

Or is there any hook in an Openshift pod life cycle that triggers email when pod is down.

Edited:
Can i make use of preStop hook with get api to send email?

Example,

lifecycle:
preStop:
exec:
command: ["curl", "-XGET", "http://URL"]

**Openshift version that we are using is 3.11 & i guess that doesn't support prometheus.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenShift comes with a full monitoring/alerting stack, for OCP itself but also for your own workloads.
It is easily configurable.
You then configure alert manager to send email for selected alerts (ie `"PrometheusRules"`)

- [Understanding the monitoring stack](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/monitoring/understanding-the-monitoring-stack.html)
- [Enabling monitoring for user-defined projects](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/monitoring/enabling-monitoring-for-user-defined-projects.html)
- [Managing alerts](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/monitoring/managing-alerts.html)

Comment: Could you please tell me how we can add alert specifically for my scenario?

Comment: Openshift version that we are using is 3.11 & i guess that doesn't support prometheus.